# Combination and merge of the string

Tags: php

how can I combine this

5 4 3 2 1 1 (an array id)

3 3 2 1 3 2 (an array value)

and I want output is like this for array(value)

```
id  value
5 - 3
4 - 3
3 - 2
2 - 1
1 - 3
1-  2
```

Comment: what is the logic you want to apply ? what did you try ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Array merge combination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518570/array-merge-combination). You've asked this before. Also, StackOverflow is not your personal "do this for me, I'm too lazy to" resource

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array  = array(5=>3, 4=>3, 3=>2, 2=>3, 1=>2);

foreach($array as $key=>&$val){
   $val  = $key."-".$val;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like thi works for you

```
$array  = array(5=>3, 4=>3, 3=>2, 2=>3, 1=>2);

foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    $value  = $key."-".$value;
    $array[$key] = $value;

}

 var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$id = array(5 , 4 ,3 ,2, 1, 1) ;
$value = array(3 , 3 , 2, 1, 3, 2);

foreach ( array_map(null, $id, $value) as $group ) {
    vprintf("%d - %d\n", $group);
}
```

Output

```
5 - 3
4 - 3
3 - 2
2 - 1
1 - 3
1 - 2
```